# Assign number to names

Tags: r, assign

I have two table. One of them contain four column, the first column are names and other three column are numbers. I want to assign the mean of the numbers to the name.

```
ID   number_1  number_2  number_3
A01  13        11        12
A02  18        16        17
......
```

The second table have a column contain the names from the first table and I want to replace the names with the mean of the numbers. For example:

```
v1  v2  v3  ......
8   5   A01 ......
6   3   A02 ......
```

replace the name so I can get:

```
v1  v2  v3  ......
8   5   12  ......
6   3   17  ......
```

I have no idea how to do this. Hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both of your tables are dataframes and that they have the same order (i.e. A01, A02 etc.)

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID   number_1  number_2  number_3
                         A01  13        11        12
                         A02  18        16        17",
                 header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "v1  v2  v3
                          8   5   A01
                          6   3   A02", 
                  header = T)

df1means <- rowMeans(df1[2:4])

df2$v3 <- df1means

df2

#    v1 v2 v3
# 1  8  5  12
# 2  6  3  17
```

Comment: It should be `df1[2:4]`.

Comment: They didn't have the same order.